# Semi-inner product structure in complex Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$. Any $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$) induces a semi-inner product on $F$ defined as:
$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{M}:F\times F\longrightarrow\mathbb{C},\;(x,y)\longmapsto\langle Mx, y\rangle,$$

> Now let 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \mathbb{M}=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\
> C & D
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation*}
>   be a positive operator on $F\oplus F$. Does $\mathbb{M}$ induces a semi-inner product on $F\oplus F$?

Note that the inner product on $F\oplus F$ is defined as follows: If $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\in F\oplus F$ with $x_1,x_2\in F$, and $x'=\begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\ x_2'\end{pmatrix}$ similarly, then
$$\langle x,x'\rangle_{F\oplus F}:= \langle x_1,x_1'\rangle_F +\langle x_2,x_2'\rangle_F.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say yourself, **any** positive bounded operator on a Hilbert space induces a semi-inner product. Your $\mathbb M$ is a positive bounded linear operator on the  Hilbert space $F\oplus F$, so indeed it induces a semi-inner product on $F\oplus F$.

Comment: How we define the semi inner product?I think M should be diagonal

Comment: I fail to see what problem you perceive. You define $$(x,y)=\langle \mathbb M x,y\rangle. $$

Comment: @Schüler, $M$ doesn't have to be diagonal, although in some generalized sense it may be "diagonalizable".